In reactJs solana wallet integration, how can I get my token balance
I am currently creating a web3 staking app for a solona blockchain token in reactjs. how can I get balance of a specific token? I can only get the balance or sol balance of the wallet not the specific token.
list of tokens inside the login wallet with its current balance
const  getBalance = async () => {
  const newBalance =  await connection.getBalance(publicKey); 

  const elsaMintAddress = new PublicKey("Haj7CedKUSb44fHfcddypYFac33bKqBkNgtBFaTkpump");
  const tokenAccounts = await connection.getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner(publicKey, {
  programId: new PublicKey("TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"),
});

const elsaAccount = tokenAccounts.value.find(
  (account) =>
    account.account.data.parsed.info.mint === elsaMintAddress.toString()
);

  return {
    newBalance,
    elsaAccount
  }
}

elsaAccount is always undefined
